# Calculating age with currval in postgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers, currval

I have created a database with a People table which contains all the information for people such as their first name, last name, gender,date of birth, and email. Each row in this table has a serial peopleID. I am trying to create a stored procedure and trigger to automatically calculate the age of a person that was just entered. I am trying to use currval to get the last inserted peopleID.

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PersonAge (peopleID INT)
RETURNS INTERVAL AS
$$
DECLARE
birthday date := (SELECT People.dateOfBirth
        FROM People
        );
BEGIN
RETURN age(birthday);
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

This is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CalculateAge
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON People
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE PersonAge( SELECT currval(‘people_id_seq’));
```

This is the error I am getting when I try to implement it with an insert statement:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "currval"
LINE 5: EXECUTE PROCEDURE PersonAge( SELECT currval('people_id_seq')...
                                        ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "currval"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 116
```

Comment: trigger function with argument?..

Comment: I think I am a little confused as to what specific elements I need here. I am fairly new to triggers.

Comment: sure thing. I picked up docs for you to read - look in my answer

Comment: no worries. we are here to help

Answer (score 0):

You pass arguments in not supported way, please r[ead docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)

> Note that the function must be declared with no arguments even if it
> expects to receive some arguments specified in CREATE TRIGGER — such
> arguments are passed via TG_ARGV, as described below.

and

> TG_ARGV[]
>
> Data type array of **text**; the arguments from the CREATE TRIGGER
> statement. The index counts from 0. Invalid indexes (less than 0 or
> greater than or equal to tg_nargs) result in a null value.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: This would make available in TG_ARGV the value of `currval(‘people_id_seq’)` when you issued `CREATE TRIGGER CalculateAge`, not when it was executed on `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. I have no idea what the author wants to do though.